# Ruby on Rails 7 rendering .rtf.erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rtf

I am new in Ruby on Rails and I am trying to render `.rtf.erb` template and I understand it requires some third party plugins or libraries and I found something like [rtf gem library](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rtf), [rrtf library](https://github.com/whileman133/rrtf) but I am looking to do something in different way.

I have template in `./views/order.rtf.erb` and I am sending/rendering order details to this template and want to download in RTF format.

The content looks like below with ruby tags:

```
.
.
.
\trowd \trgaph108\trleft-108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10 \clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr
\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb \cellx3690\clvertalt\cltxlrtb \cellx5940\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb \cellx8910\pard \nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright {\fs16 
\par }\pard\plain \s15\nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright \fs16\cgrid {\f1 SOLD TO:
\par }\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright \fs20\cgrid {\f1 
\par <%= @client_addr.addr1 rescue 'N/A'%>
\par <%= @client_addr.addr2 rescue 'N/A'%>
\par <%= @client_addr.addr3 rescue 'N/A'%>
\par <%= @client_addr.city rescue 'N/A'%>, <%= @client_addr.state rescue 'N/A'%> <%= @client_addr.zipcode rescue 'N/A'%>
\par }{\fs16 \cell }{\cell }{\fs16 
\par }\pard\plain \s15\nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright \fs16\cgrid {\f1 SHIPPED TO:
\par }\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright \fs20\cgrid {\f1 
\par <%= @shipping_addr.addr1 rescue 'N/A'%>
\par <%= @shipping_addr.addr2 rescue 'N/A'%>
\par }\pard\plain \s16\nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright \fs20\cgrid {\f1 <%= @shipping_addr.addr3 rescue 'N/A'%>
\par }\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright \fs20\cgrid {\f1 <%= @shipping_addr.city rescue 'N/A'%>, <%= @shipping_addr.state rescue 'N/A'%> <%= @shipping_addr.zipcode rescue 'N/A'%>
\par }{\fs16 \cell }\pard \nowidctlpar\widctlpar\intbl\adjustright {\row }

\pard \nowidctlpar\widctlpar\adjustright { \par }
.
.
.
```

My controller's function:

```
def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    raise NotFound unless @order
    if params[:format] == 'rtf'
      latest_order = Order.find_by(order_type: 'o', customer_id: @order.customer_id)
      if latest_order.nil?
        @client_addr = Customer.find(@order.customer_id).addresses[0]
        @shipping_addr = @client_addr
      else
        @client_addr = latest_order.client_address
        @shipping_addr = latest_order.shipping_address
      end

      # Construct an object representing the RTF document
      rtf = RRTF::Document.new

      #==========================================
      #here I do not have any idea what to do...
      #==========================================
      
      #what i did
      rtf = File.read(Rails.root.to_s+ "/app/views/order.rtf.erb")
      # Convert document into RTF string
      send_data rtf, filename: 'order', type: 'application/rtf'

      #render template: "order.rtf.erb", formats: :rtf, layout: false
  else
    render
  end
end
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for extra libraries if the RTF file will not be generated dynamically. In your example you have an RTF file with embedded ERB, so it's just a question of putting that file into [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/erb/ERB.html) and  and letting it do its magic.

Something like this should work:

```rb
def show
  # ...

  rtf = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "/app/views/order.rtf.erb"))
  # Load the file as an ERB template
  erb_template = ERB.new(rtf)
  # Executes the generated ERB code to produce a completed template
  output = erb_template.result(binding)
  # Convert document into RTF string
  send_data output, filename: 'order', type: 'application/rtf'

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you and I did as you mentioned and it is working fine.